# specific cast is not valid combobox c#

Tags: c#

**Please help me to select combo box list form database**

```
 void fillCombo2()
    {
        try
        {
            cc.con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            cc.con.Open();
            cc.cmd = new SqlCommand("Select kod_jawatan from jawatan", cc.con);
            cc.rdr = cc.cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (cc.rdr.Read() == true)
            {
                int kID = cc.rdr.GetInt32(0);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(kID);
                //comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged will change the index to textbox 



            }
            cc.con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

**but I get the following exception : Specified cast is not valid.**

Comment: Remove the try-catch and tell us in which line the exception is thrown.

Comment: what is the datatype of kod_jawatan column in database?

Comment: Output `ex.StackTrace` and tell us where the exception is thrown. I guess at `cc.rdr.GetInt32(0);`. What type is `kod_jawatan` in the database?

Comment: i got the answer. the datatype of kod_jawatan varchar. so its not an intiger datatype.   the code should be a string. thanks for help. string sname = cc.rdr.GetString(0);